# Get pointer to onscreen keyboard view on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

I am working to tint all UI elements reddish in an astronomy app.  I have successfully done this for basically everything except the onscreen keyboard.  I need to get a reference to the keyboard's Window or View in order to do this.  I have not found anything in the API for doing so.

Can anyone suggest a way for me to get hold of this?  I have seen postings explaining (a hack for) how to learn when the keyboard is shown or hidden, but not to actually get a reference to the view.

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest a way for me to get hold of this?

Write your own input method editor and hope users use it. You cannot affect other developers' code this way.

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to affect other developer's code.  I only use the system supplied soft keyboards.  It is not totally clear why this would be any different that being able to redden the system alert dialogs which I can do without problems.  Are the system input method editors really totally locked down?

Comment: @btschumy: I know of no way for you to "get a reference to the keyboard's Window or View". While your objective is reasonable (and might be useful for darkrooms and other light-sensitive situations), I have no idea how you'd pull it off, short of writing your own IME, or contributing a patch to an existing open source one to allow for a configuration option for tint.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the info.